# How to create a data frame with the following csv?

Tags: pandas, jupyter

Hello I am working with a csv that looks as follows:

```
field1,field2,field3
user1,"information",1
user2,"information",0
user3,information,2
```

I would like to créate a data frame from this using pandas I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
df1=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\acamagon\Downloads\MyComments.csv",sep=',',columns=['field1','field2','field3'])
```

print(df1)

However I got the following error, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to overcome this issue:

```
  File "<ipython-input-53-ba9e69f7c66b>", line 3
    df1=pd.read_csv("C:\Users\acamagon\Downloads\MyComments.csv",sep=',',columns=['field1','field2','field3'])
                   ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that python is treating the backslashes in your filename string as escape characters.

You can either use forward slashes instead of backslashes to specify the path

```
"C:/Users/acamagon/Downloads/MyComments.csv"
```

or preface the string with `r` to specify that python should not treat the backslashes as special characters

```
r"C:\Users\acamagon\Downloads\MyComments.csv"
```

As a side note, you don't need to specify the column names in the `read_csv` call unless you want to change them -- pandas will try to read them from the first row.

Comment: Thanks this was very useful, the problema was fixed